# Get exception when stubbing a property

Tags: testing, rhino-mocks

When I run the following test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var wizardCatalog = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IWizardCatalog>();

        var firstQuestion = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IWizardQuestion>();
        wizardCatalog.Stub(i => i.GetFirstQuestion()).Return(firstQuestion);

        var choices = new List<IWizardChoice>();
        firstQuestion.Stub(i => i.Choices).Return(choices);
    }
```

I get this exception:

> You are trying to set an expectation on a property that was defined to
>   use PropertyBehavior. Instead of writing code such as this:
>   mockObject.Stub(x => x.SomeProperty).Return(42); You can use the
>   property directly to achieve the same result: mockObject.SomeProperty
>   = 42;

Everything I read tells me that this stub operation is valid:

```
        var choices = new List<IWizardChoice>();
        firstQuestion.Stub(i => i.Choices).Return(choices);
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PropertyBehaviour` is on by default on stubs, but not on mocks. So you can either continue using a stub and change to the syntax suggested in the exception, or create a mock with `GenerateMock<IWizardQuestion>()` and use your existing `.Stub(...).Return(...)` syntax.

Comment: That worked for me. I wish there was a good screen cast or something on Rhino Mocks. The documentation is rather sparse.